# Has Sun's Unified Logging Format ever been published anywhere?

Tags: java, logging, format, sun

Back in the days when I was still at Sun Microsystems, there used to be a document that explained the Unified Logging Format in great detail. It's still [referenced a lot](http://www.google.nl/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ulf&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=YfFUTZHNIYmIhQfipbjsDA#sclient=psy&hl=nl&client=safari&rls=en&q=ulf+unified+logging+format+sun+microsystems&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=ca2a901c65d1d6fc) in the documentation of Sun / Oracle's middleware, but I have never been able to find a reference to a public version of that document.

So the questions is: has it *ever* been published on the web? Or is there a chance it could be shared now? I mean, it seems a little silly to talk about it all over the place, but never explain what it actually means, and why it would be a sensible idea to adopt *that format*.

I would love to get my hands on that document again, because I think people put quite a bit of thought in it.

Comment: did you find it at all though other means?

Comment: Nope, didn't. :-( Best kept secret in the world.

Answer (score 1):

I arrived here while searching for a formal spec for the ULF format as it comes out of (for example) payara. In case someone else arrives here with similar questions: I couldn't find any documentation, but:

The code for the formatter is here: [UniformLogFormatter.java](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/master/nucleus/core/logging/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/server/logging/UniformLogFormatter.java)

Code for a parser can be found here: [UniformLogParser.java](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/master/nucleus/core/logging/src/main/java/com/sun/enterprise/server/logging/parser/UniformLogParser.java)

Answer (score 0):

This site references the spec saying it's development is dead.

http://trac.adium.im/wiki/XMLLogFormat

Here's a discussion group for the spec... last change Aug 2007 :-(

http://groups.google.com/group/ulf-discuss/about?pli=1

Comment: I don't think this is the same thing though.